# I'd like to play wav file in my vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, audio

I'm calling this function in my App.vue app

```
var audio = new 
Audio("./foley_50_and_20_pence_peice_coins_put_down_on_surface.mp3")
audio.play()
```

but getting this error
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Comment: is this file name correct? also the extension .mp3?

Comment: The audio file was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import audioRes from '@/foley_50_and_20_pence_peice_coins_put_down_on_surface.mp3';

export default {
    name: "App",
    mounted() {
        var audio = new Audio(audioRes);
        audio.play();
    }
};
```